# What meaning exactly does べ have in the Hokkaido dialect?

Tags: dialects, sentence-final-particles

In the Hokkaido dialect, it's common to end sentences with particles such as だべ, だべさ, べや, べか and others which involve the particle べ. However, what comes as strange to me is the fact that the meanings contained in each kind of ending seem to bear no relation whatsoever, and so I can't really grasp the meaning of べ. To illustrate what I mean, here are some examples:

- バンドと言えばピストルだべさ　＝　バンドと言えばピストルだよね
- お風呂も沸かすべ　＝　お風呂も沸かそう

So, what is the exact meaning of the sentence ending べ in the Hokkaido dialect?

Comment: If you understand Classical Japanese: [べし](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%97)

Answer (score 3):

It mostly corresponds to う・よう in Tokyo dialect (≒ べし in classical).

Summing up the sources below, it means 推量・勧誘・断定.

---

From [here](https://hougen.u-biq.org/hokkaido.html)

**(推量) ～だろう / でしょう ⇒ ～べ (男性)**

- 寒いだろう ⇒ 寒いべ
- 日本人でしょう ⇒ 日本人だべ

**[意向形] / [辞書形]ぞ ⇒ [辞書形]べ (男性)**

- 飲もう ⇒ 飲むべ
- 帰ろう ⇒ 帰るべ

---

From [北海道方言#代表的な文末表現](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E6%B5%B7%E9%81%93%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#%E4%BB%A3%E8%A1%A8%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E6%96%87%E6%9C%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE)

**動詞・形容詞+「べ」、名詞+「だべ」**

> 推量および勧誘の助動詞

> 「遊ぶべ」＝「遊ぼう（よ）」、「寒いべ」＝「寒いだろうね」、「これだべ」＝「これだろう？」

**「〜（だ）べさ」（主に女性）、「〜（だ）べや」（主に男性）**

> 「そうだべさ」＝「そうでしょうよ」、「それくらい、いいべや」＝「それくらい、いいじゃないか」
> ※「（だ）べや」はいかにも男性的な荒々しい印象

> 疑問形として、「〜だべ（さ）？」＝「〜でしょう？、〜だろう？」、「あしたは雪だべな？」「うん、そうだべな。」

> 断定の意味にも「〜だべさ」を用いる。「お前が悪いんだべ（や）。」